# What is the significance of Asuna's heterochromia?

Tags: negima

In *Negima! Magister Negi Magi*, we note that Asuna has [heterochromia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heterochromia_iridum), with one green and one blue eye.  Here's a shot taken from official artwork.

[image: Official artwork of Asuna]

However, in *Negima!?*, we note that she doesn't have it at all.  Here's a shot taken from the third (I think) episode.

[image: Screenshot from third episode of Negima!?]

What is the significance, if there is any, of Asuna's heterochromia?  Why wasn't it present in the second season?

Comment: I don't think a clear reason was given, but in the manga they go more into her backstory than the anime. Usually the heterochromia trope has some backstory to it (e.g. special powers, royal birth). Perhaps that has something to do with it...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## There is no significance

[Asuna Vesperina Theotanasia Entheofushia, a.ka. Asuna Kagurazaka](http://negima.wikia.com/wiki/Asuna_Kagurazaka), has one green eye, and one blue eye, as depicted in every canon appearance except in *Negima!?* There is no real known significance as to why she has heterochromia, though it may have something to do with the fact she is of royal descent. She is seen as having heterochromia before she looses her memory, so that isn't the cause.

As far as why *Negima!?* is different, it is because it is a different studio who worked on this project, and they did [redesigns for many of the characters](http://negima.wikia.com/wiki/Negima!%3f#Characters_Appearance). *Negima!?* actually has a number of differences from the original manga.

### That we know of...

Mahou Sensei Negima (the manga) was canceled, so there were many stories that went unexplored. There is a possibility that this is something that the author was unable to reveal because it involved bigger plans around Asuna. Sadly, without speaking with the author himself, there isn't any way to know.